# AssemblyLoadContext and Assembly.LoadFrom(path)

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, assembly-loading

GetCustomAttribute cannot find attribute on an assembly loaded via "Assembly.LoadFrom(path)" in custom AssemblyLoadContext.

The load flow:

- Main app has custom AssemblyLoadContext
- Custom AssemblyLoadContext points to assembly X and loads it
- Custom AssemblyLoadContext does EnterContextualReflection
- Custom AssemblyLoadContext creates an instance of the type from assembly X
- The type does Assembly.LoadFrom(path) and successfully loads assembly Y

Assembly Y has an assembly-level attribute on it. The attribute comes from a shared assembly (TechTalk.SpecFlow) which is staticaly linked to both X and Y.

When I try to get the attribute via type-version of `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` it returns null.

When I list all attributes via `CustomAttributes` property then the attribute is there and it has exactly the same assembly fullname.

If I try to cast it to staticaly known type, then strange exception appears:

> [A]TechTalk.SpecFlow.Plugins.RuntimePluginAttribute cannot be cast to [B]TechTalk.SpecFlow.Plugins.RuntimePluginAttribute.
>   Type A originates from 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' in the context 'Default' at location 'c:\Users\yapaxi\source\repos\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.ChargingTokens\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll'. 
>   Type B originates from 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' in the context 'Default' at location 'c:\Users\yapaxi\source\repos\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.ChargingTokens\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll'.

For some reason it thinks that both assemblies are loaded to the `Default` context, which is odd, because all loading happens in the custom assembly loading context.

If I try `AssemblyLoadContext.CurrentContextualReflectionContext.Name` before `Assembly.LoadFrom` it shows the name of the custom loading context - as expected.

Why does it still think that assemblies are loaded to Default context? The main application does not even have static references to those assemblies - it does not have any custom references at all.

If I run assembly X directly (without AssemblyLoadContext) it all works well.

Env:

- net core 3.1
- SDK 3.1.201
- VS 16.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext#complications) can help you to find out the issue. Especially the section where it explains how to debug Type conversion issues with shared dependencies. The problem is that the default debugger output does not give you enough information to resolve that kind of error.